# Ошибка при попытке "смиксовать" два метода в Vue (NuxtJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, mixins

Доброго времени суток!

Понадобилось смиксовать метод дочернего компонента с базовым, чтобы заменить его поведение.
В компонентах опустил всё лишнее, чтобы вы не отвлекались на ненужный код.

Базовый компонент FilterBase.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
    #test {{ get_link }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        get_link: function() {
            return 'base'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Дочерний компонент FilterCategory.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
  FilterBase
</template>

<script>
import FilterBase from "~/components/filters/FilterBase";
import Vue from 'vue'

var mixin = {
  methods: {
    get_link: function () {
      return 'mixin'
    }
  }
}

Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.methods = function (toVal, fromVal) {
  // return mergedVal
}

export default {
  components: {FilterBase},
  mixins: [mixin],
}

</script>
```

Я знаю, что по умолчанию метод базового компонента в примесях является более приоритетным и он заменяет дочерние методы. Поэтому я добавил пользовательский компонент перезаписи (как правильно понял, достаточно просто его вставить и всё без всяких изменений), взятый из [документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9):

```
Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.methods = function (toVal, fromVal) {
  // return mergedVal
}
```

Но после вставки опций слияния я получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема?